# Pass the file name of a saved file from one class to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I'll do my best to explain.

My program takes screen shots which the user can save to their desktop or pass to a media server.

However, to pass to the server I first must have the file location of the image they are saving and so they must first save the file using the save file dialog and I store the location of that in a string which triggers a bool to say that the image has been save. The code looks like this to pass the file to server:

```
// sfd is the safe file dialog
UploadToServer.HttpUploadFile(Settings.Default.ServerAddress , sfd.FileName.ToString(), "file", "image/jpeg", nvc);
```

I tried to store the sfd in the following way so I could pass this call to another class:

```
public String SaveImageLocation
{
   get { return sfd.FileName.ToString(); }
   set { sfd.FileName.ToString() = value; }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Error  1   The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

What I'm trying to achieve is to take the file upload code and move it to another class. can someone help me with this error?

Comment: `sfd.FileName = value;`

Answer (score 3):

This is a method/function (call).

```
ToString()
```

You cannot assign a method/function (call) to a value..

```
.ToString() = value;
```

Try

```
public String SaveImageLocation
{
  get { return sfd.FileName.ToString(); }
  set { sfd.FileName = value; }
}
```

Please note you have not indicated what type `FileName` is, so it still may not work.